# jquery can't be triggered by if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I try to make `#no-noti` show up after every `.noti-button`'s parent div disappear, using an if statement but with no luck. Is there anything wrong with the code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".noti-button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow")
  });

  if( $(".noti-box-pt").css("display") === "none" ){
      $("#no-noti").fadeIn("slow");
  }

});
```

Comment: `document.ready` only fires once on page load, therefore your `if` statement is only evaluated at that time.  Otherwise, you have failed to show the relevant HTML or explained what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Sparky thanks for your response! So what should I do the next? I tried taking the if statement out of the `document.ready` but it still didn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what you should do, because I don't know what you want to do, nor can I see your HTML.

Comment: Of course taking the `if` out of the `document.ready` changes nothing because you're not calling it from anywhere.  There is apparently a fundamental misunderstanding here about how JavaScript works.

Comment: @Sparky you are right. I didn't quite understand how to use document.ready properly. I've figured this out now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the callback of `fadeOut`. It will be fired once the fadeOut has completed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".noti-button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
       $("#no-noti").fadeIn("slow");
    });
  });
});
```

**Edit** Also, consider changing your `if` statement to:

```
if( $(".noti-box-pt").is(':hidden') ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now it's working perfectly, although I had to add the if statement back, because `.noti-button` is applied to multiple items.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best method for what you're trying to accomplish, but I know you could improve the `if` statement. See my edits.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to trigger your `fadeIn()` out `fadeOut()` statements from within your click handlers.**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/tnjpe1cw/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".noti-button").on("click", function(){
    $("#no-noti").fadeIn("slow");
  });

});
```

This gives you control over the animations. Currently, your if statement would only ever be run once, when the page loads, but not when a button is clicked.

Hope this helps!